# Example of statistical properties that is lost while combining data

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics

**Question 1**: Is it possible to have dataset which can be partitioned into $n$ disjoint partitions such that each of the $n$ partition pass the same test for normality but their union does not pass this test?

**Question 2**: In general, for what statistic does there exist a data set such each of the $n$ partition show this statistic but their union does not test statistic?

Comment: Take any Gaussian mixture that's not close to Gaussian and split into the Gaussian components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding **Question 1**, the answer is yes.

For instance, the set
$$
S_j = \{ 1+10j,2+10j,\ldots,10+10j \}
$$
Is close enough to the Normal distribuiton, according to the Shapiro-Wilk test.

R code below for $j=0$:

```
> shapiro.test(seq(1,10))

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  seq(1, 10)
W = 0.97016, p-value = 0.8924
```

But if we look at the union
$$
U = \bigcup_{j=0}^9 S_j = \{ 1,2,\ldots,100 \}
$$
it fails the Shapiro-Wilk test:

```
> shapiro.test(seq(1,100))

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  seq(1, 100)
W = 0.95472, p-value = 0.001722
```

---

As for **Question 2**, we can find several examples, so I'll give a generic answer. If there are differences at the population level, when we select a sample size small enough, we will be able to find differences that are not statistical significant; but if the sample size is large enough, we can obtain a low $p$-value.